# Clearing url get parameter when page reload is forced?

Tags: javascript, php

When the user logs out on my website, he gets directed to the start page which then will have a get parameter "logged=out". This get parameter causes a little box to appear which tells the user "You have successfully been logged out". If the user decides to log in right away again, the page on which the user currently stays gets reloaded automatically. This means that if the user just logged out and logs in again, the "logged=out" parameter stays and the box shows again after the user has logged in and the start page (www.startpage.de/?logged=out) gets reloaded.

Is it possible to specify in a script that a specific get parameter gets removed on reload?

Currently I use the following command for page reload when the user logs in:

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

**EDIT:**

how about building an if-statement? if the current url contains the get parameter "logged out", then redirect user to the startpage without the get parameter... is it possible to build something like that?

Comment: `window.location.replace(window.location.href)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The request header contains some POST/GET data. No matter what you do, when you reload the page, the request wil be sent again.

The simple solution is to redirect to a new (if not the same) page.

Comment: how about building an if-statement? if the current url contains the get parameter "logged out", then redirect user to the startpage without the get parameter... is it possible to build something like that?

Comment: I dont know how you let your users log in, but you should be able to send them to the same page again with the same link but then logged in.

like href="?logged=in" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
/* if user logs in right away after having been logged out on index page, 
make sure "logged=out" parameter is not kept */
if (document.URL.indexOf('logged=out') > -1) {
        document.location.href = 'index.php';
} else {
        // do a regular reload of page
        document.location.reload(true);         
}
```